# productFlavors main ~ Gradle Error: Multiple entries with same key: main=[] and main=[]

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

When I increased gradle version to `gradle-7.3.3` from `gradle-7.2`, I receive a gradle sync error which is saying `Multiple entries with same key: main=[] and main=[]`.

When I change my productFlavors name to `mainCore` or something else then `main`, gradle syncs without an error.

I'd like to know how to keep using `main` productFlavor. Any ideas?

###### build.gradle(app):

```
    .....
flavorDimensions "mode", "client"
        productFlavors {
            /////// Distribution Modes ///////
            main {
                dimension "mode"
                versionName generateVersionName()
                manifestPlaceholders = [
                        app_label: "@string/app_name",
                        appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
                        appIconRound: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                ]
            }
            beta {
                dimension "mode"
                applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
                manifestPlaceholders = [
                        app_label: "@string/app_name",
                        appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_beta",
                        appIconRound: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_beta_round"
                ]
            } .....
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. If you find a solution, please post it. Thanks!

Comment: I changed my productFlavor from `main` to `full` in order to make it work. But I still wonder how to use `main`

Comment: My guess is that Gradle plugin 7.3+ is using `main` as a key implicitly in the build process, renaming the ProductFlavor to anything else seems to work, I choose to rename to `core`. As annoying this break may be, it was easy to workaround.